# Load page data before showing it in Next js

Tags: next.js

I have a heavy web page with a lot of images. How can I add a loader and load the page data before showing it? I'm using Next.js

I thought of doing something like this:

```
const AboutPage = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(true);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return loading ? (
    <PageLayout headProps={{ title: "We are Laugh - About" }}>
      <AboutHero />
    </PageLayout>
  ) : (
    <div>not loading</div>
  );
};
```

but I think there are better ways so I not hardcode the seconds. Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `next/image` it will lazy load images by default. Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading

Comment: Do you really need a loader? Are you using `next/image` component for your images?

Comment: @juliomalves yes I am. But in some pages I'm loading maybe 10 images in high resolution (I compress them to the maximum and still 2mb or more each)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is the wrong way to handle the loader. You can stop the loader once the API response is available.

For images, NextJs provides a loader option. (ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

An alternate way to render the page is using SSR. (ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)